# How to test a file within a folder with pytest in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, directory, pytest, python-3.8

I exchange my Pycharm community IDE for the VScode IDE because the Pycharm do not support Jupyter Notebook. I am almost config all the details that I like in an IDE, but I really caught in it.

The VScode can't find the test when they are within a folder, it does not find the tests.

> Test discovery error, please check the configuration settings for the tests

It finds it when the test files are not in a folder, Here is the structure of a "project", It's alright because the tests are out of a folder:

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLja2.png)
[tests structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jpIe.png)
I wanna put it in a folder =)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi! Tests are useful for ensuring your code doesn't break after adding new features. If you don't plan to change your code later, perhaps you could skip the tests for now.

Comment: Thank you, Greg :) I really don't explain my question in a understandable way, really sorry.

Comment: @nucsit026 I disagree with your edit. You are changing the question's tone, removing the human element from it, while not adding anything useful. Why not convert the question to JSON while you're at it? Would make it more easily readable for machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discover a way to fix this problem in the comments of another random question.

As we have a folder test, so... It's just add a **initi**.py file, as simple as that:

```
|__.pytest_cache
|__Main folder
   core.py
   something.py
|__Tests folder
   |__pycache__
   __init__.py
   test_core.py
   test_something.py
```

Thank you.

Comment: I just put this answer in my won question because I think that it's can really help another guys that have the same question easily.